# Spring boot JPA - Insert or update a list of entities

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a repo with a unique constraint on 2 fields, connection_id and token_type:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "business_api_token",
    schema = "public",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "business_api_token_unique_connection_id_and_token_type",
            columnNames = {"connection_id", "token_type"}
        )
    }
)
public class BusinessApiToken {    
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "connection_id",
      nullable = false,
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
          name = "fk_business_api_token_connection_id"
      )
  )
  private AccountingConnection connection;

  @Column(name = "token_type")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ApiTokenType tokenType;

  @Column(name = "token_value")
  private String tokenValue;
  ...
}
```

I saw some posts saying add a custom query, something like this:

```
  @Modifying
  @Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1, u.lastname = ?2 where u.id = ?3")
  void setUserInfoById(String firstname, String lastname, Integer userId);
```

But how would I do this for a list? I was doing this:

```
businessApiTokenRepository.saveAll(tokens)
```

Which gives an error.

The tokens are created elsewhere without knowledge of existing ones, I can do another query to check first but that seems inefficient, and I have to do this all over.

Thanks

Comment: do you have unique constraint on 2 fields on database level, or only inside a code with `@UniqueConstraint`? and what is your problem, that duplicates persisted into database?

Comment: Both, the @table code definition has it, and the generated sql adds it to the db, so if I try saving a duplicate it throws an error (I want to update or insert).